# Optimizing/removing loop

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have the following piece of code that I would like to optimize using numpy, preferably removing the loop. I can't see how to approach it, so any suggesting would be helpful.

indices is a (N,2) numpy array of integers, N can be a few millions. What the code does is finding the repeated indices in the first column. For these indices I make all the combinations of two of the corresponding indices in the second column. Then I collect them together with the index in the first column.

```
index_sets = []
uniques, counts = np.unique(indices[:,0], return_counts=True)
potentials = uniques[counts > 1]
for p in potentials:
    correspondents = indices[(indices[:,0] == p),1]
    combs = np.vstack(list(combinations(correspondents, 2)))
    combs = np.hstack((np.tile(p, (combs.shape[0], 1)), combs))
    index_sets.append(combs)
```

Comment: Sounds like a network problem, so look into `networkx` module maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which is vectorized over N. Note that it still contains one for-loop, but it is a loop over each 'group of key-multiplicities', which is guaranteed to be a much smaller number (typically a few dozen at most).

For N=1.000.000, runtime is order-of-magnitude one second on my pc.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
N = 1000000
indices = np.random.randint(0, N/10, size=(N, 2))

def combinations(x):
    """vectorized computation of combinations for an array of sequences of equal length

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : ndarray, [..., n_items]

    Returns
    -------
    ndarray, [..., n_items * (n_items - 1) / 2, 2]
    """
    return np.rollaxis(x[..., np.triu_indices(x.shape[-1], 1)], -2, x.ndim+1)

def process(indices):
    """process a subgroup of indices, all having equal multiplicity

    Parameters
    ----------
    indices : ndarray, [n, 2]

    Returns
    -------
    ndarray, [m, 3]
    """
    keys, vals = npi.group_by(indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1])
    combs = combinations(vals)
    keys = np.repeat(keys, combs.shape[1])
    return np.concatenate([keys[:, None], combs.reshape(-1, 2)], axis=1)

index_groups = npi.group_by(npi.multiplicity(indices[:, 0])).split(indices)
result = np.concatenate([process(ind) for ind in index_groups])
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package.

Comment: Did you give it a try? Curious to hear how it worked out in practice.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't try it yet. I had to switch to another higher priority task, but I'll definitely be using this piece of code. I'll try to test it at the end of the day and report.

Comment: I finally did some testing of the code you posted and it does produce the same results but about 26 times faster than my original code!! thanks very much for your answer and for the numpy_indexed module, I think it's a very useful module and I'll probably be using it again.

Comment: Thanks, happy to help; I found it an interesting question you posed

Answer (score 2):

Few improvements could be suggested :

- Initialize output array, for which we can pre-calculate the estimated number of rows needed for storing combinations corresponding to each group. We know that with `N` elements, the total number of possible combinations would be `N*(N-1)/2`, to give us the combination lengths for each group. Furthermore, the total number of rows in the output array would be sum of all those interval lengths.
- Pre-calcuate as many stuffs as possible in a vectorized manner before going into a loop.
- Use a loop to get the combinations, which because of the ragged pattern can't be vectorized. Use `np.repeat` to simulate tiling and do it before loop to give us the first element for each group and thus the first column of the output array.

So, with all those improvements in mind, an implementation would look like this -

```
# Remove rows with counts == 1 
_,idx, counts = np.unique(indices[:,0], return_index=True, return_counts=True)
indices = np.delete(indices,idx[counts==1],axis=0)

# Decide the starting indices of corresponding to start of new groups 
# charaterized by new elements along the sorted first column
start_idx = np.unique(indices[:,0], return_index=True)[1]
all_idx = np.append(start_idx,indices.shape[0])

# Get interval lengths that are required to store pairwise combinations
# of each group for unique ID from column-0
interval_lens = np.array([item*(item-1)/2 for item in np.diff(all_idx)])

# Setup output array and set the first column as a repeated array
out = np.zeros((interval_lens.sum(),3),dtype=int)
out[:,0] = np.repeat(indices[start_idx,0],interval_lens)

# Decide the start-stop indices for storing into output array 
ssidx = np.append(0,np.cumsum(interval_lens))

# Finally run a loop gto store all the combinations into initialized o/p array
for i in range(idx.size):
    out[ssidx[i]:ssidx[i+1],1:] = \
    np.vstack(combinations(indices[all_idx[i]:all_idx[i+1],1],2))
```

Please note that the output array would be a big `(M, 3)` shaped array and not split into list of arrays as produced by the original code. If still needed as such, one can use `np.split` for the same.

Also, quick runtime tests suggest that there isn't much improvement with the proposed code. So, probably bulk of the runtime is spent in getting the combinations. Thus, it seems alternative approach with [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) that is specially suited for such connection based problems might be a better fit.

Comment: I tried to benchmark this versus my answer, but it gave a MemoryError for N=1.000.000 :)